# How does best estimator fitting work in RandomizedSearchCV?

Tags: python, optimization, data-science, lightgbm

I used RandomizedSearchCV (RSCV) with the default 5-fold CV for LGBMClassifier with an evaluation set.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
model_LGBM=LGBMClassifier(objective='binary',metric='auc',random_state=0,early_stopping_round=100)

distributions = dict(max_depth=range(1,10),
                     num_leaves=[50,100,150],
                     learning_rate=[0.1,0.2,0.3],
                     )

clf = RandomizedSearchCV(model_LGBM, distributions, random_state=0,n_iter=100,verbose=10)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train,eval_set=(X_test,y_test))
```

So the output of the RSCV looks like:

```
First iter: CV 1/5, "valid0's" CV 2/5 "valid0's", ..., CV 5/5 "valid0's";
Second iter: CV 1/5 "valid0's", CV 2/5 "valid0's", ..., CV 5/5 "valid0's";
...
Last iter: CV 1/5 "valid0's", CV 2/5 "valid0's", ..., CV 5/5 "valid0's";
+1 fit with "valid0's"
```

I suppose the last fit is the refitted best estimator. Does it use the whole training set? Where does it use the evaluation set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs (present [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html)), if the `refit` parameter is `True` (which it is by default) the model get trained at the end using the best parameters found on the entire dataset (train data in this case) inputted.

Comment: Thanks! Does the eval_set has any effect on the fitting?

Comment: No, it shouldn't as from what I can see from the source code, the `eval_set` should be passed directly to the `fit` method of lightgbm and it only contributes to checking validation metrics, not on the actual training.